# different input color than output in terminal shell bash

Tags: bash, terminal, colors

I want Input and Output to be different colors in a GNU or Linux bash terminal shell.

I use terminals all the time for bash, R, and python.  Today I am fighting all day long to read my R and I have to manually put lots of CRLF to separate and find my place all the time.

So can you help me get terminal I/O to have different Input color and Output color?

Comment: What terminal client are you using?

Comment: The client is the best place to set background colors.  I use 6 different colors to distinguish between the machines I'm connected to.

Comment: Could you please add examples of what you mean by "input" and "output" colors? The shell prompt? The command you're typing? The data printed by your application? A question asked by your application? An answer you're typing to that app? ...

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can set a `DEBUG` trap.  From `trap`'s documentation:

```
If a SIGNAL_SPEC is DEBUG, ARG is executed before every simple command
```

You can set a `TRAP` which will echo ANSI color codes to the console (e. g. `echo -e "\e[1;33;44m"` which will change the color of output (notwithstanding any further changes by the output itself).  You can also set `PROMPT_COMMAND` or `PS1` to change the color of text which you input at the prompt for the purposes of differentiation.

Comment: This works perfectly, adding the input color to the end of PS1, then adding the trap on the next line to reset the output color, "trap 'tput sgr0' DEBUG"